# Булгаковская фраза "Поздравляю вас, гражданин, соврамши!"

Tags: литература

Все мы помним фразу из "Мастера и Маргариты": "Поздравляю вас, гражданин, соврамши!"
А что это за оборот такой? Коровьев нарочито говорил неграмотно или это какой-то устаревший вариант?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это очень интересный "оборот". Вернее – форма.
Она проявляется в таких выражениях, как "был выпимши" (выпивши), "три дня не жрамши" и проч.
С одной стороны, она безусловно не является нормативной.
С другой – широкая распространённость формы, ёмкомсть и отсутствие нормативного аналога заставляют крепко призадуматься.

Фагот, конечно, намеренно использует просторечие, причём утрированно, обычно эта форма несёт значение продолженного перфекта, подобного английскому (уже три дня не ел – и всё ещё в этом состоянии, выпил – и пока не протрезвел), здесь же – обычный однократный перфект прошедшего (один раз соврал) в устах Фагота становится продолженным, а совершённое действие тем самым – признаком его совершившего. Очень метко сказано.

ЗЫ: Булгаков – это неиссякаемый источник для подобных наблюдений.

Comment: То есть "соврамши" не наречие?